# What determines when plants grow?

Tags: plant-physiology, growth, plant-perception

I am interested in dryland ecosystems, and I am trying to find material on what determines the time at which plants in dryland ecosystems, either shrubs or grasses, grow and shoot? Is it only related to water availability? Is temperature also a factor?

Comment: Plants are not sentient beings and do not know anything. Please phrase your questions in scientific terms.

Comment: Metaphoric language that I meet here and there (http://www.whataplantknows.com/)

Comment: Best avoided. Making your words reflect and clearly communicate your thoughts is part of being a scientist.